# How to build all css and js files from a vue project to single file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using `"@vue/cli-service": "^4.3.0"` to build a vue project.

When I used `vue run build` (`vue-cli-service build`), it output a lot of css and js files to dist/css and dist/js directory.In my project, there are 600 files at that directory.

Because of some stupid users.I have to reduce the number of these files as little as possible.
It's better to output only one css file and one js file.

like:

```
all.js  { for all js }
all.css { for all css }
```

I tried

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    }
  },
}
```

and it won't work for me.

I think this may be a webpack config problem.But I don't know how to configure it, does anyone can help me.

Comment: hey, same issue here, did you found a way to build your app in just one js file? thanks in advance!